# How to filter Excel columns values by Ms-excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I want to get filter column string from below Data.

```
                    URL                          PreFix              OutPut             ConcatStrings
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
    http://AbCD.com/grouponorange-county    |     Deals   |    orangecounty |    Dealsorangecounty
```

In, 
**Column-1** first column there is an URL string. 
**Column-2** There is fixed words here ex. Deals or any fixed string
**Column-3** Want to get string after this "**http://AbCD.com/groupon**" string 
         
                 there is orange-Country then remove all special character so here output is orangeCountry. 
**Coulmn-4** ConcatString  " **[Column-2] + [Column-3]** "

How I can do in Microsoft Excel sheet.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Grzegorz_Oledzki for modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column 4: use the formula `=B:B&C:C`.

Column 3: if you always have the same hostname, you can use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"http://AbCD.com/groupon","")
```

If it has a different hostname, use:

```
=RIGHT(A:A,LEN(A:A)-FIND("groupon",A:A)-LEN("groupon")+1)
```

(edit) Use `Alt+F11` to go into VBA, go to `Insert` > `Module`, and paste this in:

```
Public Function remove_special_characters(s As String) As String
    ' based on code by Aaron Blood posted here:
    ' http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=55082&page=1

    Dim cur_char As String
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        cur_char = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If cur_char Like "[A-Za-z0-9]" Then
            remove_special_characters = remove_special_characters & cur_char
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

You can then use `=remove_special_characters()` in Excel as a wrapper around the functions above.

Comment: Thanks @KyleNZ But Also, Need Remove special symbols like " -,_,#,@,$ etc. from Column-3.